# "could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/n/a" error in elementary OS

Tags: pantheon-terminal, apt, ppa

I got message like this :

[image]

```
root@ferryready-Satellite-L510:/home/ferryready# curl -sL http://i-hate-farms.github.io/spores/install | sudo bash -
Installing the repository...
OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 91, in <module>
sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
self.reload_sourceslist()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
(self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/n/a
```

Comment: Please use headlines that are describing your problem

Comment: please [edit] and add output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Also please  [edit] post and add output of  `cat /etc/lsb-release` and `cat /etc/os-release`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The possible fix*:

`sudo apt-get install gksu` # If not installed

`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386` # If you get Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" error

Now `gksudo nano /etc/lsb-release`

The file should be like,

> DISTRIB_ID="elementary OS"
>   DISTRIB_RELEASE=0.3.1
>   DISTRIB_CODENAME=freya
>   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS Freya"

*Note*: Use this for fresh installation of freya, I am not sure for upgrading from luna.

Comment: yesterday i tried to uninstalled the Xdman it's working but the icon still on my desktop. please tell me how to removed it completely

Comment: @ferry ok, let us solve other( new) post :) see my answer