# Error while adding PPA on elementary OS freya

Tags: apt, ppa

Whenever i try to add **any** PPA it shows me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 91, in 
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/n/a``
```

Output of `cat /etc/lsb-release` (editing it to `elementary-os` did not solve the problem)
`$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"`

Output of `cat /etc/os-release`

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Solution at ["could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/n/a" error in elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/could-not-find-a-distribution-template-for-ubuntu-n-a-error-in-elementary-os) does not solve my problem.

Comment: i have the same issue!
did you already solved?

Comment: The error code from the issue appears identical to the discussion you linked. If it's different, would you please explain what didn't work from the existing answer?

Answer (score 1):

That line 91 line 109 ordeal was a bug. Most of the tickets I found in [Launchpad (the bug tracker)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/) went [ultimately unresolved](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=181919), but perhaps they just weren't the main ticket.

Have you tried updating your system and installing "Software & Updates" to install the PPA manually?

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
```

Has the problem been resolved and does it persist into your Loki upgrade?