# Can't Add Repository "Could not find a distribution template for elementary/hera"

Tags: release-hera, ppa

I wanted to add Inkscape repository to download Inkscape 1.0 which is not available in the default elementary repository. Before I've ever done sudo add-apt-repository and it just worked fine. Only recently when I tried to add Krita's repo it didn't work and have some `aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for elementary/hera` so I did a workaround by manually adding the link to synaptic. But the problem is, ppa for Inkscape is not a http but ppa: and when I tried to manually do the same it couldn't find the repository.

Here's the full result of `sudo add-apt-repository`

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 107, in 
> sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 117, in **init**
> self.reload_sourceslist()
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 612, in reload_sourceslist
> self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
> (self.id, self.codename))

> aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for elementary/hera

There's a similar question [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/could-not-find-a-distribution-template-for-ubuntu-n-a-error-in-elementary-os) but I guess it only works for Freya.

edit:

Here's the output of `tail /etc/lsb-release`

> DISTRIB_ID=elementary
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=5.1.3
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=hera
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera"

Comment: Can you please add to your question the output of `tail /etc/lsb-release` ?

Comment: this is the output

`DISTRIB_ID=elementary
DISTRIB_RELEASE=5.1.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hera
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera"`

Comment: While not a solution to your specific issue, you could install Inkscape 1.0 from Flathub as elementary OS officially supports Flatpak packages unlike PPAs: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.inkscape.Inkscape

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape are availble from Flathub, ready to be installed. ;)

https://flathub.org/apps/search/inkscape

Comment: Yes I know, but it's not about Inkscape. It's about PPA. I can't add any repository at all (I know it's not recommended by elementary but sometimes I prefer classic apt than Flatpak)

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this (workaround i guess) by following [this article](https://comandandodebian.wordpress.com/2018/03/29/arreflar-problema-add-apt-repository-ppa/).

It worked for me on elementaryOs Hera

1. wget http://blog.anantshri.info/content/uploads/2010/09/add-apt-repository.sh.txt
2. Edit script: change lucid to bionic (line 14)
3. sudo cp add-apt-repository.sh.txt /usr/sbin/add-apt-repository
4. sudo chmod o+x /usr/sbin/add-apt-repository

done!